# How do I get the data about a user gotten from an external login provider into his ClaimsIdentity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, katana

I am getting data about a user from his LinkedIn profile using Katana for OAuth. I would like to get all the data I received from LinkedIn into the user's `ClaimsIdentity` object so I can send it to the `AspNetUserClaims` table in the ASP.NET membership database.

I am not completely lost. I've subscribed to the `OnAuthenticated` event of the LinkedInAuthenticationProvider and deserialized the raw JSON into a bespoke business object. Now, I would like to access this object from the `ApplicationUserManager` so I can send it to the database. That's where I am stuck.

```
var options = new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions();
options.ClientId = "...";
options.ClientSecret = "...";
options.Provider = new LinkedInAuthenticationProvider
{
    OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
    {
        // I would like to get this bespoke object
        // of type LinkedInBasicProfileResponse
        // into the UserManager<TUser, ...>
        var basicProfile = 
             context.User.ToObject<LinkedInBasicProfileResponse>();

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
};

app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(options);
```

I would like to see that basic profile object in here:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, 
                        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here
        // I would like to add that data to these claims
        var claims = userIdentity.Claims;

        foreach(var claim in claims)
        {
            Debug.Print(string.Format($"{claim.Value}, {claim.ValueType}, {claim.Issuer}, {claim.OriginalIssuer}, {claim.Type}"));

            foreach(var property in claim.Properties)
            {
                Debug.Print(string.Format($"{property.Key}, {property.Value}"));
            }
        }

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

One way to do it, of course, would be to put it in the `HttpSessionState` dictionary. But I was hoping there would be a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

After calling `CreateIdentityAsync` within your code, you can simply use the `AddClaim` method on `userIdentity` as follows:

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FavouriteDrink", "Beer"));
```

The full code would become:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, 
                        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom claim
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FavouriteDrink", "Beer"));
        var claims = userIdentity.Claims;

        foreach(var claim in claims)
        {
            Debug.Print(string.Format($"{claim.Value}, {claim.ValueType}, {claim.Issuer}, {claim.OriginalIssuer}, {claim.Type}"));

            foreach(var property in claim.Properties)
            {
                Debug.Print(string.Format($"{property.Key}, {property.Value}"));
            }
        }

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My question is not which method to call to add a claim, but how do I get the information that I put in a bespoke object over here. Is there a more elegant way than to put it in the `HttpSessionState` object? My end goal is to get whatever claims I received from a third-party external provider into the claims table. Is there an in-built object or method in AspNet.Identity that carries the *actual* data / claims that the external provider sent?